# Error sending server side user-to-user request with Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the Facebook C# SDK (.NET 3.5) and I am trying to make a basic, server side user to user request from within my app. For example, I have a game and players can challenge other players. After a player goes through the FB auth process, they can pick a Facebook friend to play against, play their game, and once the game ends, I want to send a server side FB challenge request from the player that initiated the challenge (challenger) to the player that was challenged (the challengee). The error and my code is below.  The only people that can be challenged are those players that have already authorized the app so it's not an auth issue.

**Error Message**

(OAuthException - #2) (#2) Failed to create any app request.

**Code/Method for Sending The Request**

```
private void sendFbChallengeRequest(int challengeeId)
{
var app = new FacebookClient(Session["AccessToken"].ToString());
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters["message"] = "I have challenged you to a game!";
parameters["title"] = "I challenged you!";
parameters["to"] = challengeeId;
var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)app.Post("/" + challengeeId + "/apprequests", parameters);
}
```

The error is happening on the last link of the method: var result = (IDictionary)app.Post("/" + challengeeId + "/apprequests", parameters);

Any help on this would be appreciated.  Tx in advance!

Comment: Since you are doing it server-side it can not be a user-to-user request, only an app-to-user request – and those need to be made using the app access token. (Whereas I assume what you are getting out of the session is a user access token …?)

Comment: Ok, understood.  I thought you could do a user-to-user request based on the currently logged in user but now that I can't, this changes my strategy of course.  So with that, do I simply add a new parameter for "app access token", populate that, then try using the same code as is?  What is the name of the app access token parameter?

Comment: It’s `access_token` as well.